# what's the purpose of variable val in this algo

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search-tree, red-black-tree

it's an algo from internet about Red-Black BST Java implementation. I am confused about the variable named `val` in this program. Here is the code:

```
package tools;
public class redBlack2 {
    private static final boolean RED   = true;
    private static final boolean BLACK = false;
    private Node root;
    public redBlack2() {}
    private class Node {
        private int key;
        private int val;
        private Node left, right;
        private boolean color;
        public Node(int key, int val, boolean color) {
            this.key = key;
            this.val = val;
            this.color = color;
        }
    }
    private boolean isRed(Node x) {
        if (x == null) return false;
        return x.color == RED;
    }
    public int get(int key) {
        return get(root, key);
    }
    private int get(Node x, int key) {
        while (x != null) {
            if      (key < x.key) x = x.left;
            else if (key > x.key) x = x.right;
            else              return x.val;
        }
        System.out.println("There is no such key.");
        return 0;
    }
    public boolean contains(int key) {
        return get(key) != 0;
    }
    public void put(int key, int val) {
        root = put(root, key, val);
        root.color = BLACK;
    }
    private Node put(Node h, int key, int val) {
        if (h == null) return new Node(key, val, RED);
        if      (key<h.key) h.left  = put(h.left,  key, val);
        else if (key>h.key) h.right = put(h.right, key, val);
        else if (key == h.key)  h.val   = val;
        if (isRed(h.right) && !isRed(h.left))      h = rotateLeft(h);
        if (isRed(h.left)  &&  isRed(h.left.left)) h = rotateRight(h);
        if (isRed(h.left)  &&  isRed(h.right))     flipColors(h);
        return h;
    }
    private Node rotateRight(Node h) {
        Node x = h.left;
        h.left = x.right;
        x.right = h;
        x.color = x.right.color;
        x.right.color = RED;
        return x;
    }
    private Node rotateLeft(Node h) {
        Node x = h.right;
        h.right = x.left;
        x.left = h;
        x.color = x.left.color;
        x.left.color = RED;
        return x;
    }
    private void flipColors(Node h) {
        h.color = !h.color;
        h.left.color = !h.left.color;
        h.right.color = !h.right.color;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        redBlack2 r = new redBlack2();
        r.put(34,1);
        r.put(23,2);
        r.put(65,3);
        r.put(73, 4);
        System.out.print(r.get(73));
    }
}
```

is that just a mark we give to the number we put inside the Tree? then don't we already have key as a mark? why we still need variable `val`?

Comment: Suppose someone gives you a dictionary you've never seen before.  You decide to look up a word.  When you find the word, the dictionary doesn't tell you anything about it--no pronunciation, no definition, no anything, just the word.  You don't know any more than you did before (except that you know the word is in the dictionary, which is a little bit, but not much).  Wouldn't it be more useful to have a dictionary that provides more information along with the word?  Does that help explain what `val` is for?

Comment: `val` stores the value given in call to `put(int key, int val)` and later returned by `get(int key)`. Why do you believe the value of `key` is the same as the value of `val`? If you simply follow the code to see where the value comes from and where it is used, the answer is just that.

Comment: Similarly, Java provides both `Set` and `Map` collections.  A `Set` can look up a key and tell you whether the key is in the set, but it can't tell you anything more.  A `Map` allows you to provide additional data associated with the key.  Does that help explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're right, it's just like a mark. We can indeed implement this algorithm with just one variable, i.e., `key`. In this algo, `val` is something that is being stored as a type of data for which we need to keep track.

For example consider this

> You have several numbered boxes like 34, 23, 65, 73 and you want to
>   implement RB Tree operations on them. So these number on boxes
>   resembles the `key` in your algorithm.
>
> Now consider each box contains a number of balls in it. These balls
>   can be seen as a data which is stored inside the box and you need to
>   keep a track of it. So this can be considered as `val`.

You can even go a step further and keep a track of several things that are inside a box by changing the data-type of `val` to `List` or `Map` or even user-defined objects. It will still work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

In this implementation, this data structure acts like a `Map`, which means it maps keys to values. That `val` is a common abbreivation of `value`, which is quite self-explainatory. It could be of any type existing in Java, be it primitive or reference.